# How to make mirror like/click div to affect other div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I coded this schedule grid, I want the user to click on UK hour and then the hour in U.S time to be highlighted and was wondering if you can do this via css? ***I want multiple hours to be selected.*** I've looked at a few examples but they only work with one div.

[image: Schedule Grid]

This was built with tables so my code looks something like

```
<table>
    <tr class="booked">
      <th><a href="">00 am</a></th>
      <th><a href="">01 am</a></th>
      <th><a href="">02 am</a></th>
      <th><a href="">03 am</a></th>
      <th><a href="">04 am</a></th>
      <th><a href="">05 am</a></th>
      <th><a href="">06 am</a></th>
      <th><a href="">07 am</a></th>
      <th><a href="">08 am</a></th>
      <th><a href="">09 am</a></th>
      <th><a href="">10 am</a></th>
      <th><a href="">11 am</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="booked_active">
      <th>4 pm</th>
      <th>5 pm</th>
      <th>6 pm</th>
      <th>7 pm</th>
      <th>8 pm</th>
      <th>9 pm</th>
      <th>10 pm</th>
      <th>11 pm</th>
      <th>12 am</th>
      <th>1 am</th>
      <th>2 am</th>
      <th>3 am</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**Note: There will be 7 of these grids, one for every day of the week.**

Comment: AFAIK, This is not possible in CSS can you provide your JS (and CSS) on how you are even doing the highlighting? This can be achieved using Javascript.

Comment: This cannot be done with pure CSS. I would suggest jQuery: use a `data` attribute to assign the UTC for each time. When one is clicked, add a class to those with the matching UTC time.

Comment: If you are already using JQuery I think a simple solution would be to use [JQuery UI Multi-seclet](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/) (if you are not to savvy with JQuery)

Comment: @Cheruvian I'm not good with JS that's why I was wondering if it was possible with CSS. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can easily be done if you are using jquery

this will also work both ways.. they can either click on the top or bottom..

please note that i did not style or specify specific Jquery selectors.
if this interferes with other code on the page you may have to change the selectors.

to give different colors just modify the CSS..

```js
$('th').on('click',selectTimes)

function selectTimes(){
 $('[hour="'+$(this).attr('hour')+'"]').toggleClass('selected');
}
```

```css
th {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
.booked .selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.booked_active .selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="booked">
    <th hour="1">00 am</th>
    <th hour="2">01 am</th>
    <th hour="3">02 am</th>
    <th hour="4">03 am</th>
    <th hour="5">04 am</th>
    <th hour="6">05 am</th>
    <th hour="7">06 am</th>
    <th  hour="8">07 am</th>
    <th hour="9">08 am</th>
    <th hour="10">09 am</th>
    <th hour="11">10 am</th>
    <th hour="12">11 am</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="booked_active">
    <th hour="1">4 pm</th>
    <th hour="2">5 pm</th>
    <th hour="3">6 pm</th>
    <th hour="4">7 pm</th>
    <th hour="5">8 pm</th>
    <th hour="6">9 pm</th>
    <th hour="7">10 pm</th>
    <th hour="8">11 pm</th>
    <th hour="9">12 am</th>
    <th hour="10">1 am</th>
    <th hour="11">2 am</th>
    <th hour="12">3 am</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This seems like a more easier approach, can multiple times be selected instead of just one?

Comment: How can I add a different color select for the UK times so the user wont get confused?

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS you can select one hour at a time. If you want more then one element, you'll have to use JS.

You can do this using CSS with [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target):

> The :target pseudo-class represents the unique element, if any, with
>   an id matching the fragment identifier of the URI of the document.

For this to work you need an id for each element you wish to highlight, link with a hash with the id text, and css rule for each element:

```
<th><a href="#cell1">00 am</a>
</th>

<th id="cell1">4 pm</th>

#cell1:target {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
#cell1:target {
  color: red;
}
#cell2:target {
  color: red;
}
#cell3:target {
  color: red;
}
#cell4:target {
  color: red;
}
#cell5:target {
  color: red;
}
#cell6:target {
  color: red;
}
#cell7:target {
  color: red;
}
#cell8:target {
  color: red;
}
#cell9:target {
  color: red;
}
#cell10:target {
  color: red;
}
#cell11:target {
  color: red;
}
#cell12:target {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="booked">
    <th><a href="#cell1">00 am</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="#cell2">01 am</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="#cell3">02 am</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="#cell4">03 am</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="#cell5">04 am</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="#cell6">05 am</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="#cell7">06 am</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="#cell8">07 am</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="#cell9">08 am</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="#cell10">09 am</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="#cell11">10 am</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="#cell12">11 am</a>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="booked_active">
    <th id="cell1">4 pm</th>
    <th id="cell2">5 pm</th>
    <th id="cell3">6 pm</th>
    <th id="cell4">7 pm</th>
    <th id="cell5">8 pm</th>
    <th id="cell6">9 pm</th>
    <th id="cell7">10 pm</th>
    <th id="cell8">11 pm</th>
    <th id="cell9">12 am</th>
    <th id="cell10">1 am</th>
    <th id="cell11">2 am</th>
    <th id="cell12">3 am</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Woah nice! Is there a way to select multiple of these tho? I want users to select multiple hours.

Comment: @SergioEstrada - unfortunately no. I've missed the **multiple** in your answer, and just seen it now.